# Is it possible to dedicate a space to an app, as opposed to the other way around?

Tags: spaces

I always have emacs running in full screen on one of my spaces. Currently, I assign it to particular space, and assign every other app I use to some other space. This is kind of inefficient, as I have to assign every app I use individually, when really, my purpose is to make sure that they never open in the same space as emacs. In fact, I actually would rather not have to dedicate most apps to any space, since I'd generally like to just use them in the space I started from, unless that space is the space with fullscreen emacs in it. As it is, I'm only really able to use two spaces effectively (one with emacs assigned to it, one with everything else assigned to it).

What I'd like to do is make it so that the emacs space is effectively dedicated to emacs, so if you try to open any other app in that space, it opens in another space, without assigning every other app to a particular space. Has anyone implemented functionality like this? I don't mind if I have to use a script or a paid app.

Comment: Full-Screen apps cannot share a Space with any other app, which makes your question somewhat confusing. (They also do not have, nor can be assigned , a Space number)

Comment: Well, emacs can. I can tell you that. Emacs of course has never been a well-behaved application in any operating system.

Comment: Since it seems that this is an emacs specific issue, I guess I will ask there. The version of emacs with this issue is `GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1404.47) of 2017-07-07` from `railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport` on Homebrew.